# Symmetric matrices are a subspace of the space of $n\times n$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

[image]

Hey, I'm trying to learn how to properly prove this problem.  Any advice on how to go about this problem?

Comment: Not the most descriptive title in the world.

Comment: Hint : what is the standard basis ($E_{ij}$) for $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ and how will you prove they form a basis? same idea will work here

Comment: To show it is a subspace, you ought to show that if $A,B$ are symmetric then so is $A+B$ and $\lambda A$ for any scalar $\lambda$. The zero matrix is obviously symmetric. To show it is a basis, you ought to show that any symmetric matrix can be written as a linear combination of those, and show they are linearly independent.

Comment: @Pedro Tamaroff it seems by $A^{'}$ you mean $A^t$ which is a standard notation for transpose in many books. you can change it to B no?

Comment: @GA316 No, $A'$ is just some other matrix, not the transpose.

Comment: @Pedro Tamaroff I have understand it. Just I am pointing out there is a small chance to people confuse with the transpose.

Comment: @GA316 You're right. I have edited to avoid any confusion.

Comment: @Pedro Tamaroff Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to check that the sum of symmetric matrices is symmetric, and that any multiple of a symmetric matrix is symmetric. Hence it is a subspace.

To see that ${\cal B}$ is a basis, you must show that (1)  all symmetric matrices can be created using the linear span of ${\cal B}$, and (2) that the elements of ${\cal B}$ are linearly independent.

Note that a symmetric $A$ is completely defined by its entries $[A]_{ij}$ where $1\le i\le j\le n$. Hence we can write $A= \sum_{1\le i\le j\le n} [A]_{ij} S_{(i,j)}$, so it follows that all symmetric matrices lie in the linear span of ${\cal B}$.

Suppose $\sum_{1\le i\le j\le n} \alpha_{ij} S_{(i,j)} = 0$. If $e_k$ is the vector of zeroes with a one in the $k$th position, we have
$e_a^T(\sum_{1\le i\le j\le n} \alpha_{ij} S_{(i,j)}) e_b = \sum_{1\le i\le j\le n} \alpha_{ij} e_a^T S_{(i,j)} e_b = \alpha_{ab} e_a^T S_{(a,b)} e_b = n^2 \alpha_{ab} = 0$. It follows that $\alpha_{ab} = 0$, and so ${\cal B}$ is linearly independent.

The dimension of a subspace is the cardinality of a basis. Hence $\dim S = |{\cal B}|$. We see from the above that $|{\cal B}| = |\{ (i,j) | 1\le i\le j\le n \} | = n+ \frac{1}{2}(n^2-n) = \frac{1}{2}n (n+1)$.

Answer (score 0):

First, check that $S$ is a subspace.  This requires you check that if $A \in S$, then $cA \in S$ for all $c \in \mathbb{F}$, depending on your field.  Also you should show that $A,B \in S \implies A+B \in S$.

Then you want to compute a basis.  My recommendation is to find the smallest set of matrices consisting of $1's$ and $0's$, each one symmetric, such that any symmetric matrix can be formed by looking at linear combinations of the matrices.

Finally, if $n=3$, you'll notice that you constructed the previous set by considering $3+(3+2+1)$ matrices. So when $n = 3$ the dimension of $S$ is $9$.

Comment: I guess the only thing I don't understand is how you got the basis.  How do you find the "smallest set" exactly?

Comment: I think you meant $3+ (2+1) = 6$.

Comment: Yeah I agree with copper.hat.  I don't know why the extra 3 was added.

Comment: In general, should the dimension of S be calculated as (n(n+1))/2 ?